# Analyzing a Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I would like to know if an IQueryable object's Expression contains a certain "Where clause".

For example, given as IQueryable instance, which could be something like:

```
var query = customers.Where(c => c.Name == "Test");
```

How can I determine if the query is filtering the customers by Name?

Comment: I think it would help to explain your final goal.  Are you wanting to add a Where clause if one is not found?  There may be some rearranging of logic to get what you want.

Comment: Pretty sure this would be non-trivial in the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to walk the expression tree ([IQueryable.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx)), if you are on .NET4 [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323984.aspx) class helps.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the way to go.